# Perché un marito tradito viene definito “cornuto”?

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Treccani cita la seguente definizione di  ***[cornuto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cornuto1/)*** :

> 2. pop. Titolo d’ingiuria al partner tradito, riferito generalmente all’uomo, raramente alla donna: *marito cornuto, o, come sostantivo, un cornuto.*

inoltre  cita la seguente etimologia:

> agg. [dal lat. cornutus, der. di cornu "corno"], pop. - [che è vittima di tradimento amoroso: marito cornuto] ≈ (scherz.) cornificato, tradito.

Purtroppo non spiega il nesso tra le corna ed il tradimento coniugale.
Qualcuno ha maggiori informazioni a riguardo?

Comment: Una spiegazione che non mi sembra troppo fantasiosa è il riferimento al “becco” (maschio della capra); dalle mie parti si dice infatti “beco” invece di “cornuto”.

Comment: Ho trovato in diversi siti almeno due origini: una fa risalire la cosa a Minosse e il minotauro (Minosse tradito dalla moglie con un toro) l'altra fa risalire l'origine a Bisanzio; quando l’imperatore Andronico I Comneno abusava delle mogli dei suoi nemici e appendeva alle mura dei loro palazzi  le corna dei cervi uccisi nelle battute di caccia, a mo' di sfregio.
https://cultura.biografieonline.it/perche-si-dice-mettere-o-avere-le-corna/
http://www.pilloledistoria.it/8267/medioevo/origini-medievali-dellespressione-mettere-le-corna

Comment: Anche in catalano si usa questo modo di dire ("posar les banyes"). Questo [sito web](http://origenfrasesfetes.blogspot.com/2015/02/posar-les-banyes.html?m=1) afferma che la cosa ha a che vedere con i vichinghi: nel medioevo, i segnori feudali vichinghi avevano il diritto di possedere sessualmente le donne dei contadini e indicavano che lo stavano facendo appendendo dei corna alle porte (spiegazione che però mi sembra molto fantasiosa).

Comment: E anche in spagnolo si dice "poner los cuernos" con lo stesso significato.

Comment: La stessa [domanda posta in Spanish.SE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17904/why-in-spanish-putting-horns-means-to-cheat-your-partner) con alcune risposte interessanti.

Comment: Quand'ero piccolo ho letto su *Focus* che si trattava di un riferimento ad Apelle (con una storia improbabile su un ariete che aveva disegnato sulla cintura di castità della moglie), ma l'affidabilità di quella rivista è purtroppo sottozero...

Answer (score 5):

Il libro [*The Origins of European Thought about the Body, the Mind, the Soul, the World, Time, and Fate*](https://books.google.es/books?id=PdE7AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA243&lpg=PA243&f=false), di Richard Broxton Onians, spiega come i riferimenti più antichi alla associazione tra questi due concetti (marito tradito e corna) che si conoscono si trovino in testi della Grecia antica:

> In any case, if 'horn' had in early times such sexual significance, we can understand, as it has not been possible
> hitherto, how a man's wife, who receives lovers, prostituting herself ([...]), could be said 'as the saying is, to make horns for him' ([...]).<sup>3</sup>  She thus supplements him. Possibly there is a joking suggestion also of her working for his benefit. From such an idiom it would be but a step to say that the husband who 'has many a Paris in his house' ([...])<sup>4</sup> has horns. The lemma to this epigram describes him as [...]. These appear to be the earliest references to this association. Mediaeval poems<sup>5</sup> (e.g. in the thirteenth century) show a belief that a horn grew upon the forehead of him whose wife had received a lover. Presently it was a custom in England and elsewhere in Europe for neighbours to put actual
> horns upon the head of the husband, apparently to show with what his wife had supplemented him.
> [...]
>
> <sup>3</sup>  Artem. *Oneir.* II, 12 (not in some MSS. See Hercher, *ad loc.*).
> <sup>4</sup>  *Anth. Pal.* XI, 278. Since it produced wealth, the horn or the wife responsible might jokingly be referred to as a 'horn of plenty'. See *Anth. Pal.* XI, 5, Jonson, *Every Man in His Humour*, III, 3, Shakespeare, *Part II of King Henry IV*, 1, 2.
> <sup>5</sup> See Grimm, *Deutsches Wörterb.* s.v. Horn, col. 1817.

I testi dove si trovano questi riferimenti antichi sono l'*Oneirocritica* di Artemidoro di Daldi e l'*Antologia Palatina*.

Ad ogni modo, espressioni analoghe sono di uso comune in parecchie lingue occidentali. Ad esempio:

- "poner los cuernos" e "cornudo" in spagnolo,
- "posar les banyes" i "cornut" in catalano,
- "porter des cornes" in francese.

Guardando l'[accezione num. 8 del termine "corno" sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI03/00000795.jpg), possiamo vedere che la prima attestazione nella lingua italiana di espressioni come  "fare,  porre, mettere, piantare le corna" per indicare che una moglie tradisce il marito è dalle [*Proverbia super natura feminarum*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI_indice_autori/00235.jpg) del Duecento:

> E  la plantà le corne a l’enperer Ferico.

Cercando invece ["cornuto"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI03/00000799.jpg) sullo stesso dizionario, vediami la prima attestazione con questo significato è di [Luca Pulci](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI_indice_autori/00236.jpg) (Quattrocento):

> Folco  sapea  di  Malducco  lo  in­ganno,  /  che  dipinto  l’avea  come  cattivo,  /  e  porta  lui, come  i  soldati  fanno,  /  cornuto  a  quattro,  che  è  super­lativo.

Comment: Ho omesso i testi in greco perché sono incapace di riprodurli.

Answer (score 4):

Questa non è (per ora?) una vera risposta: vorrei che vi raccogliessimo attestazioni nell'italiano dei primi secoli di “cornuto” (o mettere le “corna” o simili) per cercare di capire quando e come queste immagini siano entrate specificamente nella lingua italiana, a prescindere dalla loro diffusione già in ambito classico.

Dall'*Enciclopedia Dantesca* apprendiamo che in Dante “corno” e “cornuto” non sono mai usati in questo senso, ma già nel *Decameron* del Boccaccio, nella 5ª novella della Settima giornata, una donna dice al marito geloso:

> io giuro a Dio, se voglia me ne venisse di porti le corna, se tu avessi cento occhi come tu n’hai due, el mi darebbe il cuore di fare i piacer miei in guisa che tu non te n’avvedresti.

Suppongo che vari altri esempi si possano trovare nelle altre raccolte di novelle coeve e successive, così come nella Commedia dell'Arte. E nelle opere buffe di Sette/Ottocento non era raro che la partitura prevedesse, alla comparsa di un marito tradito, che si sentissero i corni dell'orchestra.

Comment: Ricordo una spiegazione di Jan Willem de Vriend, un direttore d'orchestra che è di frequente a Barcellona, sull'opera *Lo speziale* di Haydn, con libretto di Goldoni, nella quale si usavano i corni dell'orchestra con questo senso, ma adesso non rammento in quale momento.

Comment: Per un esempio famoso dell'uso del corno nelle opere, l'aria [*Il core vi dono*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVqyzNCgbDY) da *Così fan tutte* di Mozart (la prima volta circa attorno a 1:45, poi varie volte fino alla conclusione). Dopo che te l'hanno fanno notare è impossibile non sentirlo (per contesto, lei è promessa sposa ad un altro e l'intera opera è una decostruzione del concetto di fedeltà). Un altro è [questo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-LWhJrmQvA), più o meno ogni volta che Figaro dice *il resto nol dico* c'è un piccolo colpetto di corno...

Comment: Vedi l'[accezione num. 8 sul GDLI](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI03/00000795.jpg) e in [PDF](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI03/GDLI_03_ocr_795.pdf). La prima attestazione è dalle [*Proverbia super natura feminarum*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI_indice_autori/00235.jpg) del Duecento.

Comment: Cercando invece ["cornuto"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI03/00000799.jpg) (in [PDF](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI03/GDLI_03_ocr_799.pdf)), la prima attestazione con questo significato è di [Luca Pulci](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI_indice_autori/00236.jpg) (Quattrocento).